# ORACLE: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification with no obvious error

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, plsql

I am running

```
<CFQUERY DataSource="#XXX.DSN#">
    UPDATE FUNKUS_LIST
    SET 
    <CFIF OPERATIONRECEIVED IS "Enable">
        FUNKUS_STATUS_ID=<CFQUERYPARAM value="1"
        CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    <CFELSEIF OPERATIONRECEIVED IS "Revoke">
        FUNKUS_STATUS_ID=<CFQUERYPARAM value="3"
        CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    </CFIF>
    WHERE
        FUNKUS_LIST_ID in (
        <CFQUERYPARAM   value="#form.dltCheckbox#"
        CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER"
            LIST="Yes">
            )
</CFQUERY>
```

in coldfusion MX7 with an oracle 9i database. What could possibly be causing:

> Error Executing Database Query. ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column,
>   table.column, or column specification

form.dltCheckbox should be a checkbox group on the form.

FUNKUS_LIST_ID is an integer column and the manual listed numbers are correct and valid IDs. OPERATIONRECEIVED is a string representing what should be done in this action form. I've confirmed all of the column and table names match

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table that might be causing problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the list = "true" attribute to your cfqueryparam:

```
WHERE
        FUNKUS_LIST_ID in (
        <CFQUERYPARAM   value="#form.dltCheckbox#" LIST="TRUE"
        CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER"> )
```

... also add a closing paren

*edit*

In response to your comment - have you verified that OPERATIONRECEIVED is definitely either "Enable" or "Revoke"?  If it is something other than those, then your SQL will be incomplete, since there will be no columns listed in the set clause.

Comment: Sorry, somehow didn't get it in there that I have a list declaration. Editing question now...still have the error.

Comment: Well I believe it to be correct. It would come from something such as       <input name="Operation" id="dltRevokeButton" type="submit" value="Revoke"></input> in the form.

Comment: Please verify that it really is one of those values.  If it is keyed off of a submit button, like you say, it's very likely that form field isn't being sent - it's easy to submit forms without clicking a button (say, by pressing enter in a text input box), in which case no value would be present.

Comment: Yeah man, it's really keyed off that value and it's triggered by a human button click. I've been trying to find ways to dump the values on some variables listed above but I am definitely not a coldfusion developer

Comment: you can dump the variables included in the post like so: <cfdump var="#form#"> and variabled included in the URL as part of get request like so: <cfdump var="#url#">

Comment: Going to +1 you and accept. You didn't give me the exact answer but by following your instructions with CFDUMP I was able to find faulty logic in another part of the application that was causing this issue.

Comment: It would be nice for people who come across this question if you could update your question with the steps you had to take to fix it (if only in vague terms, at least).  Cheers!

Comment: It was a misspelled variable that isn't in the quoted text. What would the best strategy be?